# Mnemonics for learning hiragana and katakana (other than Heisig)?

Tags: writing-system, electronic-resources, japanese, physical-resources

I'm looking for resources that use mnemonics for the [hiragana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana) and [katakana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana) syllabaries. I am aware of Heisig's book *Rememberting the Kana* (about which we already have a [question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/404/800)), but this book have been criticised for being over the top in the sense that it applies to kana an approach that was originally designed for memorizing kanji.

The resource I am looking for can be physical or electronic.

Answer (score 5):

One handy resource is [*Kana Pict-o-graphix*](http://www.worldcat.org/title/kana-pict-o-graphix/oclc/31776525) by Michael Rowley (Stone Bridge Press, 1995).

This is a pocket-sized book (roughly 7 by 13 cm) containing just 70 pages. It contains a short introduction, followed by 55 pages with mnemonics. The top half of each page presents a mnemonic for a hiragana character; the bottom half presents a mnemonic for a katakana character. The mnemonic is simply a drawing that helps you remember the pronunciation of a character. Unlike Heisig, Rowley does not use textual mnemonics. Due to the book's small size, there are no stroke order diagrams; this may be the book's only drawback.

The last section of the book dedicates one page each to the following aspects: voiced sounds, unvoiced sounds, doublers, combined forms, and look-alikes.

There are also a number of YouTube videos with mnemonics for kana:

- Linguistaholic: [How to easily remember hiragana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFZiIg-8CQk) (10 minutes);
- Linguistaholic: [How to easily remember katakana] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODDBBWizGH8) (4 minutes; many of these mnemonics look like those from Rowley's book).