# What are general cognitive principles that could explain why Heisig's method works?

Tags: learning-methods, chinese, japanese

This is a follow up to [this question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/404/4939) on *Remembering the Kana*.

[James Heisig](https://www.amazon.com/James-W.-Heisig/e/B000APGVBC) is author of a famous series of books involving learning [Chinese](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824833236) and [Japanese](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824835921) [characters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824831640). These books are

- Remembering the Kanji [sample](https://nirc.nanzan-u.ac.jp/en/files/2012/12/RK-1-6th-edition-sample.pdf) (PDF).
- Remembering the Hanzi [sample](https://nirc.nanzan-u.ac.jp/en/files/2013/11/RH-S1-sample.pdf) (PDF).

What are general cognitive principles that could explain why Heisig's method of ***remembering the ...*** works?